# VBA não reconhece valores

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou tentando pegar valores do tipo data de determinada célula do excel, porém, minha macro não reconhece os valores da célula, mesmo ela estando preenchida (data). Lembrando que são três sheets.

```
  With Worksheets("TEMP") 
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TEMP").Activate
    minDate = WorksheetFunction.Min(Worksheets("TEMP").Range("F2:F65000"))
    maxDate = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range(.Range("F2"), .Range("F65000")))
    numMonths = 1 + DateDiff("m", minDate, maxDate)
    If (numMonths < 3) Then
        countMonths = 3
    Else
        countMonths = numMonths
    End If
End With
```

O minDate e maxDate retornam como 0, apenas quando eu manualmente, clico sobre a célula e aperto Enter ou clico em outra celula a macro reconhece, apenas aquela célula.

Como fazer com que a macro reconheça aquele valor?

Comment: Seus `.Range` na quarta linha estão errados. Você deveria fazer igual a função de cima. O `minDate` funciona corretamente para mim.

Comment: Na verdade ambos funcionam quando eu clico em alguma célula manualmente e aperto enter ou clico em outra célula. O problema é a célula "inativa".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub Teste()  
  Dim MinDate As Date
  Dim MaxDate As Date  
  MinDate = WorksheetFunction.Min(Sheets("Plan1").Range("A1:A100"))
  MaxDate = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("Plan1").Range("A1:A100"))  
  Debug.Print MinDate
  Debug.Print MaxDate  
End Sub
```

Funcionou perfeitamente, verifique se os dados foram inseridos como data no intenvalo, caso não for, faça uma conversão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]